# Missing Sidekiq url helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

In our routes file we have:

```
require 'sidekiq/web'
# ...
mount Sidekiq::Web, at: '/sidekiq'
```

but `sidekiq_web_url` url helper doesn't work

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Comment: I get an error say the method doesn't exist, this method must have been available on an older version of the gem

Answer (score 0):

Rails doesn't create helpers for URLs it doesn't create.  Put '/sidekiq' in your template.